# How do I transfer user-inputted value from html to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If a user of my website inputs a value into an html  text box and clicks on a submit button..

how can I transfer/use their value to javascript so I make a calculation based on their input.

Also how can I display their value on the site?

Thanks!
((New to javascript and stackoverflow))

Comment: Well, since you are new to Stack Overflow. How about you take a [tour] and check out the [ask] page on how you can ask a good question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like this in your HTML

```
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" id="txt" class="searchField"/>
```

And something like this in your JavaScript

```
var the_value_i_am_looking_for = document.getElementById('txt').value;
```

Note that the txt is the id of the input tag, and we use that same id to identify the element in JavaScript.

The variable **the_value_i_am_looking_for**  should hold the value that you will use to make your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<input id="cost" type="number" />
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Enter a value" /> 

<div id="valueEntered" > </div>
<div id="afterTax" > </div>
<script> 

function calculate() 
{ 


valueEntered.innerHTML = " You entered : " + cost.value; 
afterTax.innerHTML = " After tax : " + cost.value * 1.3;  


} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You meant something like the following? It's a input box and a button. Once the button is clicked, the user input in the input box will be displayed below the input box and the button.

```
<input id="foo"/>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = document.getElementById('foo').value
" type="button">Click me</button>
<div id="bar"></div>
</code>
```